# ¿Como forzar ordenamiento?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día.

tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ControlARV') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #ControlARV;   

    create table #ControlARV 
    (
         ID                 int identity (1,1)NOT NULL
        ,NHC                varchar(20)       NOT NULL
        ,IdEsquema          int
        ,IdEstatus          int               NOT NULL
        ,DescripcionEstatus varchar(100)
        ,FechaEsquema       date              NOT NULL
    )

    insert into #ControlARV  (NHC, IdEsquema, IdEstatus, DescripcionEstatus, FechaEsquema )
    select  NHC, IdEsquema, IdEstatus, DescripcionEstatus, FechaEsquema
    from
    (                                                                               
                  select '100216'   NHC,    111 IdEsquema , 1   IdEstatus   ,'Continúa'                 DescripcionEstatus  , '2018-11-08'  FechaEsquema
        union all select '100216'      ,    111           , 1               ,'Continúa'                                     , '2018-12-07'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    111           , 1               ,'Continúa'                                     , '2019-02-07'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    111           , 1               ,'Continúa'                                     , '2019-04-08'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    111           , 23              ,'Suspende por Otras Causas'                    , '2019-05-09'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    156           , 18              ,'Inicia Por Cambio'                            , '2019-05-09'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    111           , 23              ,'Suspende por Otras Causas'                    , '2019-05-09'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    156           , 23              ,'Suspende por Otras Causas'                    , '2019-08-06'      
        union all select '100216'      ,    154           , 18              ,'Inicia Por Cambio'                            , '2019-08-06'      
    )t
```

en esta creo este indice cluster para lograr el ordenamiento que necesito:

```
ALTER TABLE [#ControlARV] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_NHC_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    ID ASC
   ,NHC
   ,FechaEsquema ASC
)
```

Si hago un select a la tabla, me mostrara este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede apreciar, la fila 5 y 7 están duplicadas, y se requiere dejar solo uno de los dos registros, entonces se procede a hacer un group by para eliminar el registro duplicado:

```
select      
             NHC                
            ,IdEsquema      
            ,IdEstatus
            ,FechaEsquema   
    from #ControlARV arv1       
    group by 
     NHC                
    ,IdEsquema      
    ,IdEstatus
    ,FechaEsquema
    order by 
      NHC               
    ,IdEsquema      
    ,IdEstatus
    ,FechaEsquema
```

pero el resultado que obtengo altera el orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El motor de sql ordena por la columna `IdEsquema`, lo que hace perder el orden que necesito mantener. Ya intente usar `WITH (INDEX([PK_NHC]))` para forzar el ordenamiento pero no lo consigo.

Que me falta para lograr mantener el ordenamiento que necesito, debería quedar como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Esta lista resultante la obtuve asi:`

```
select           1  ID,'100216' NHC ,111 IdEsquema  ,1  IdEstatus   ,'2018-11-08' FechaEsquema
union all select 2    ,'100216'     ,111            ,1              ,'2018-12-07'
union all select 3    ,'100216'     ,111            ,1              ,'2019-02-07'
union all select 4    ,'100216'     ,111            ,1              ,'2019-04-08'
union all select 5    ,'100216'     ,111            ,23             ,'2019-05-09'
union all select 6    ,'100216'     ,156            ,18             ,'2019-05-09'
union all select 7    ,'100216'     ,156            ,23             ,'2019-08-06'
union all select 9    ,'100216'     ,154            ,18             ,'2019-08-06'`
```

Comment: a) No muestras la columna `id` que es el primer campo del índice, por lo que lo que no puede verse a simple vista si lo que expones coincide con los datos. b) Un conjunto de datos SQL, de acuerdo al estándar, no tiene ningún orden específico. Por ello existe la clausula `order by` del `select`, ¿por qué no la usas?

Comment: edite la pregunta, agregue la columna ID, si la agrego y hago group by, el registro duplicado permanecerá,

Comment: sugiero que Incluyas la sentencia `select` con el `group by`, eso le dará más claridad a la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acuerdo al estándar *SQL*, el resultado de una sentencia `select` no tiene ningún orden específico, a menos que se indique explícitamente con una cláusula `order by`.

Desde este punto de vista, ningún motor está *obligado* a producir un resultado ordenado de alguna manera particular. Dicho en otras palabras, el mismo motor puede producir resultados en distinto orden para el mismo conjunto de datos de entrada y la misma sentencia `select` si no se incluye una clausula `order by`.

Si quieres un orden particular, la única manera de forzar al motor a hacerlo es indicarlo explícitamente mediante un `order by`.

En tu caso, para conseguir el resultado que buscas, ya que estás agrupando para *desaparecer* la fila duplicada, sugiero que obtengas el `min(id)` para cada grupo y utilices esta columna para ordenar.

Por ejemplo:

```
select   min(ID) MinID
       , NHC                
       , IdEsquema
       , IdEstatus
       , DescripcionEstatus
       , FechaEsquema
  from #ControlARV 
 group by NHC                
       , IdEsquema
       , IdEstatus
       , DescripcionEstatus
       , FechaEsquema
 order by min(id)
```

Con tus datos de ejemplo, esto produce la siguiente salida:

```
MinID  NHC      IdEsquema IdEstatus DescripcionEstatus           FechaEsquema
------ -------- --------- --------- ---------------------------- ------------
1      100216   111       1         Continúa                     2018-11-08
2      100216   111       1         Continúa                     2018-12-07
3      100216   111       1         Continúa                     2019-02-07
4      100216   111       1         Continúa                     2019-04-08
5      100216   111       23        Suspende por Otras Causas    2019-05-09
6      100216   156       18        Inicia Por Cambio            2019-05-09
8      100216   156       23        Suspende por Otras Causas    2019-08-06
9      100216   154       18        Inicia Por Cambio            2019-08-06

(8 rows affected)
```

Comment: Genial, gracias... pero, porque a pesar de tener un indice cluster, indicarle al motor que utilice ese indice y ademas agregar la clausula order by, el motor sigue indizando de otra manera ?

Comment: No hace falta que le indiques al motor que índice utilizar. En una tabla tan pequeña, dudo que tenga algún efecto en el desempeño. Por otro lado, la pregunta de por qué lo ordena de otra manera, solo los diseñadores del motor pueden responderla con autoridad. Desde mi punto de vista, como simple usuario mortal del motor, es porque el estándar les da esa libertad. Conozco un poco más de detalle técnico, pero en realidad, no viene al caso. Como dije ya en mi respuesta, el mismo motor puede producir resultados en distinto orden para el mismo conjunto de datos si no hay una clausula `order by`.

Comment: @EmersonRios El problema es que no existe un orden de ejecucion real. El motor hace unos calculos de como le va a convenir ejecutar la consulta, y en base a eso ejecuta la consulta. El orden de los factores en este caso, altera el producto. Para evitar esas optimizaciones, muchas veces lo que se hace es hacer subconsultas con el resultado de la anterior para ver que se ejecute en un determinado orden, a costa del tiempo de ejecucion.

Comment: Entiendo, agradezco las explicaciones.. En realizad la tabla tiene miles de registro, pero solo publique una muestra para simplificar la explicación. De nuevo agradezco su experiencia.

Comment: Igual, dejemos algo en claro.. el orden es correcto segun el orden que pediste.. a vos no te parecia correcto.. pero 154 esta antes que 156.. siempre!

Comment: Y ahora que miro bien.. tendriamos que tener toda la tabla.. esta respuesta esta bien para este set de datos.. pero hay que ver si en miles de datos, lo del ID minimo funciona, ya que el orden no es logico.

Comment: claro entiendo ese punto,  creo que por error publique con el order by incluyendo el IdEsquema que como bien señalas el 154 esta antes de 156, pero en realidad el order by que estaba usando era solo order by FechaEsquema, sin embargo el resultado era siempre el mismo.