# ¿Qué sentencia se puede usar para extraer registros en lotes de 500.000 filas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, favor necesito ayuda para extraer filas por lotes de 500.000 de una tabla de 3.600.000 registros, algo parecido a:

```
SELECT TOP 500000 * FROM TABLA
WHERE ID_GEO IS NOT NULL
```

pero sin perder el orden de extracción de los datos, y poder generar archivos .csv(con 500.000 cada uno) desde el mismo Managment Studio.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: [Asi](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-importar-exportar-datos-a-sql-server-utilizando-el-asistente-para-importacion-y-exportacion-de-sql-server/)

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿Cómo defines el orden de las filas?

Comment: El orden es por una columna NOMBRE (ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC).

Comment: Que quiere decir: ¿sin afectar el orden de extracción? Quizás debas leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/293103/21

Comment: ¿El proceso lo vas a hacer Manual, solo necesitas saber como traer los siguientes 500K registros?

Comment: Exacto @jachguate, quiero saber como hago la siguiente sentencia a los primeros 500k registros.

Comment: No es suficiente utilizar el `nombre` si no es determinista. Si por ejemplo el nombre *juan* coincide que es para las rows 499.999, 500.000 y 500.001. Nada impide que  digamos el primer *Juan* la sentencia lo recupere en la primera select, y te lo vuelva a devolver en la segunda select, perdiendo por el camino al segundo *Juan*. Puedes añadir tantas columnas a order by como necesites hasta que sea determinista. Puedes utilizar, nombre y la columna que sea clave primaria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En SQL Server, debes indicar el orden a utilizar, y puedes utilizar la construcción `skip N rows fetch next M rows only` al final de tu sentencia select, para extraer el segundo *lote* puedes usar, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA
WHERE ID_GEO IS NOT NULL
order by columna
OFFSET 500000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500000 ROWS ONLY
```

para el tercer lote, sería:

```
OFFSET 1000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500000 ROWS ONLY
```

Y así sucesivamente.

Sobre el ordenamiento, no puedes dejar de usar la cláusula `order by`, para más información, lee esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/293103/21

Comment: Gracias!!, funcionó a la perfección.